# How can i build async method from scratch?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to convert sync method to run as asynchronous

Simple example :

```dart
Future<void> increment() async {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
      _counter++;
    }
  }
```

When I use this code with flutter the app will freeze, because the code content is running as sync, so now I want to know how can I make this code run as async?

i tried to add `Future.delayed` as following :

```dart
Future<void> increment() async {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
      _counter++;
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(microseconds: 1));
    }
  }
```

But in some scenarios, it will takes too long time!
Is there a better solution?

Comment: Asynchronous operations are good when you need to wait for I/O during your operation. If you, on the other hand, wish to perform a lengthy, synchronous calculation parallel to the UI thread, you should run it in an [Isolate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html).

Comment: @jlahd Isolate is takes 2.5MB at memory this is a problem for me, i am building a package with asynchronous methods

Comment: this async mehtod, you ask for, is using `isolates` and event loop. Future, await, Stream, all build on that foundation

Answer (score 1):

Use [Isolates](https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency) in Dart for heavy calculations

There is [compute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute-constant.html) constant in Flutter api for top-level and static functions who manage with Isolates by themselves.

Comment: Isolate is takes 2.5MB at memory this is a problem for me, i am building a package with asynchronous methods

Answer (score 0):

Look into this page [Concurrency in Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency)

Paste the following code into a test.dart file, and see how you can create an async method from scratch using isolates.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';

void main() async {
  // Read some data.
  final result = await Isolate.run(_readAndParseDart);
  print("Called the async function");
}

String _readAndParseDart() {
  final fileData = File("test.dart").readAsStringSync();
  print('Finished the asynchronous code');

  return fileData;
}
```

Also try this code and notice the difference (which result will be printed first) when we do not use the async/await when calling the asynchronous method:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';
    
    void main() {
      // Read some data.
      final result = Isolate.run(_readAndParseDart);
      print("Called the async function");
    }
    
    String _readAndParseDart() {
      final fileData = File("test.dart").readAsStringSync();
      print('Finished the asynchronous code');
    
      return fileData;
    }
```